# Download Pdf which created using pdfkit library in nodejs through angular frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, pdfkit

```
async createpdf(){

const doc = new PDFDocument();

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('example.pdf'));

// content of the pdf

doc.end();
}
```

I used the nodejs and angular for my project. In order to export pdf I used the pdfkit library and exported the pdf. But I need to download pdf when clicking the button in the angular frontend.
Can you explain how to download the pdf when clicking the button in the angular front end?

this is the code which i added in component.ts

```
exportToPdf(){
  this.classroomService.createpdf();
  this.subscription = this.classroomService.alertMessageOccured
  .subscribe((alert) => {
   if (alert.code == 200) {
    this.alertService.clear();
          this.alertService.success(alert.message);


        } else {
          this.alertService.clear();
          this.alertService.error(alert.message);
        }
 })
}
```

This is the code of button

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right" (click)="exportToPdf()">
              Export to PDF
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the pdf was successfully created, return success/fail result to your client

in order to let the user know if it was failed,

if succeed so make a request to a download route

```
app.get('/download-pdf', function(req, res){
  const pdf_file = `${__dirname}/your_file.pdf`;
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
  res.download(pdf_file); 
});
```

this is a simple example but keep in mind further to return a unique id for download a specific file, or have any other auth check.